# Script for search and delete only files created by me in Google Drive shared folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

After numerous attempts, I still can't make the script parse only the files that I created, as Google doesn't allow me to delete files created by others, I need it to parse only my files.

**I would like the help of someone who could send me the edited script exactly the way I need to let it work properly.**

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a= new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    var b= new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return b-a;
  });
  obj.shift();
  var fileIDs = obj.map(function(e) {return e.id});
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
  });
};
```

I won't list all the ways I tried to do because the question would get too big and I know here prefer the most straightforward questions possible.

I can not pay someone to do it for me, so I am asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to delete the files you created.

  - The files are put in a shared folder.
  - The files include the files which were created by several users.
  - The files you want to delete are as follows.

    - Files which were created 3 hours ago. In this case, there are the files which are created by you and other users.
    - For the files which were created 3 hours ago, you want to leave only the latest file.
    - While you follow the above condition, you want to delete only the files you created.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

From your script and question, I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modification points:

- In your situation, when `"email" in owners` for the search query as `and` is added, only the files you created are returned. By this, your goal cannot be achieved. So `var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');` is required to be used.

In this case, how about checking the owner at `fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {Drive.Files.remove(fileID)}`?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the emails of owners are retrieved, and when the files are deleted, the owner is checked and deleted it. By this, only the files you created can be deleted.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function of `getOldFileIDs()` and `deleteFiles()` as follows.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()}); // Modified
  }
  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a= new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    var b= new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return b-a;
  });
  obj.shift();
  return obj; // Modified
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var email = "###"; // Added
  var obj = getOldFileIDs; // Modified
  obj.forEach(function(e) { // Modified
    if (e.owner == email) { // Added
      Drive.Files.remove(e.id); // Modified
    }
  });
};
```

- When you use this script, please set your email address to `var email = "###"`. Or you can also use `var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`.

### Pattern 2:

When the files that you are not owner are deleted, an error occurs. In this pattern, the error is ignored. By this, only the files you created can be deleted.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function of `deleteFiles()` as follows.

From:

```
Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
```

To:

```
try {Drive.Files.remove(fileID)} catch(e) {}
```

### Note:

- The files that you are not owner cannot be deleted. Please be careful this.

If I misunderstood your situation and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: There would be no better answer, besides solving all my doubts, still expanded my horizons to answer another problem I am having! Thank you very much

Comment: Mate... An error returned while trying to use the script → TypeError: Unable to find forEach function in function object getOldFileIDs () {...}. (line 27,

Comment: I think `var obj = getOldFileIDs;` needs to be `var obj = getOldFileIDs();`

Comment: I also think that `var email = "###";` could be `var email =Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`

Comment: Perfect mate! Done!

Comment: @Frederico Mattos Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your support.

Comment: Does this work for others? `file.getOwner()` returns null for files in a Shared Drive -- for me.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan About `Does this work for others? file.getOwner() returns null for files in a Shared Drive -- for me.`, OP's question is for the shared folder in Google Drive. That is not the shared drive. How about this?